# Why throw an exception in the unexpected handler?

Tags: c++

I have seen many code examples where the `unexpected()` function handler (as set by `set_unexpected`) itself throws an exception.

What is the point of doing that?  I thought `unexpected()` was the exception catcher of last resort.  Who will catch the exception thrown by the `unexpected()` function handler?

Comment: Exiting with an exception could still be useful, e.g. if running in a debugger or to tell the OS to create a core dump.

Comment: You may find the possible reasons after ["_A user-defined `std::unexpected_handler` is expected to either terminate the program or throw an exception_"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected_handler)

Comment: `set_unexpected` was the library counterpart of a pretty less than stellar core language feature. Dynamic exception specifications were often discouraged and are now gone. I wouldn't waste too much time studying them.